# Multiple checkbox search wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search, checkbox

I need a multiple checkbox search to work and I'm stuck. The form is ok but I don't know how to do the query. an someone please help me ?

Form :

```
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="Loft"><div class="lbl">Loft</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="Studio"><div class="lbl">Studio</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="2 pieces"><div class="lbl">2 pièces</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="3 pieces"><div class="lbl">3 pièces</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="4 pieces"><div class="lbl">4 pièces</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="5 pieces"><div class="lbl">5 pièces</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="6 pieces et +"><div class="lbl">6 pièces et +</div>
<input id="propertytype" class="noborder" type="checkbox" name="propertytype2[]" value="Proprietes, Hotels particuliers"><div class="lbl">Propriétés, Hôtels particuliers</div>
```

Query :

```
$search_propertytype = "";
if (isset($_POST['propertytype2'])) {
    $search_propertytype = trim($_POST['propertytype2']);
}


if (get_option('wp_search_propertytype') == "Yes") {    
    if($search_propertytype != '')
    {
        $search_propertytype = trim($search_propertytype);
        $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1 WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND (p1.meta_key='propertytype_value' AND p1.meta_value='$search_propertytype' OR p1.meta_key='propertytype2_value' AND p1.meta_value='$search_propertytype')";
        $sptt = getIds( $query );
        $_ids = ( !empty($sptt) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $sptt) : "" ) : "" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind the SQL injections here.

Comment: By adding this : $propertytype2 = mysql_real_escape_string($propertytype2); ?

Any idea on how to make the multiple checkbox search work?

Comment: Use prepared statements / PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution by `WP_Query` and custom meta box. Made my query argument as following:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product', 
'meta_query' => array( 
    'relation' => 'OR', 
    array(
        'key' => 'color',
        'value' => 'blue',
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Check wordpress official document: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

You can check in this way. May be it can help. Thanks.